# Stack Exchange Fellowship and Grant Program: Looking for reviewers to assess thesis proposals

Tags: discussion

Stack Exchange will be introducing a Fellowship Program awarding grants for original and independent research projects. Undergraduate Honors Theses, Independent Study Projects, Masters Theses, and Dissertations are eligible projects.

Prospective fellows will be asked to demonstrate a commitment to the discipline, approval or guidance of faculty adviser, two page proposal of the project and abstract.

Before officially introducing the Fellowship Program and calling for applications, we need experienced community members to volunteer to review applicants' two page proposals and abstracts.

Stack Exchange Fellows will be in the following subjects:

- Statistics
- Physics
- Linguistics
- Philosophy
- English

Interested in being a reviewer? Contact Seth Rogers (seth at stackexchange dot com).
Reviewers are honored as Committee Members and receive a small gift as our way of saying thank you. Keep in mind that this will not take significant amounts of your time as we are very respectful of everyone's busy schedules.